# Getting per-circuit properties in an InteractiveServer Blazor app

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to get, and then use, several properties on a per session/circuit basis (RemoteIP, browser timezone, country, & screen width). How can I do this?

The best I have come up with is to create a component that reads this, the RemoteIP in `OnInitializedAsync` and the JavaScript queries in `OnRenderAsync(true)`. And then put that component in Routes.razor.

And if that is the way to do this, do I do it as:

```
<MyCircuitProps/>
<Router>
    <!-- lots of sub nodes -->
</Router>
```

or as:

```
<MyCircuitProps>
    <Router>
        <!-- lots of sub nodes -->
    </Router>
</MyCircuitProps>
```

In either of the above cases I will have a scoped service that `<MyCircuitProps>` will then populate with the properties it reads from the system.